# Why do we use eval to pop a new window?

Tags: javascript, popup, eval

Here is the code that came across with:

```
function popUp(URL) {
   day = new Date();
   id = day.getTime();
   eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "','....;");
}
```

I don't understand why we are using eval in this case, seems like a lot of website are offering this as a solution to open a popup. Why are we not simply using:

```
var win = window.open("...");
```

Examples of this code:

[Variable sized popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362429/variable-sized-popup-window)

[Check if popup window is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137297/check-if-popup-window-is-already-open)

and more on google results

Comment: Because the authors don't know any better. It is a classic example of why the "eval is evil" mantra developed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the original developer didn't understand you could use `window['page' + id]` there to assign an arbitrarily global variable (no `var` means it goes up the scope chain, eventually assigning it to the global object, `window` in a browser).

It's also bad practice, as it's assigning a global variable based on the time (which could be much simpler `+new Date`) which is never referenced again (at least in this example).

Even it were referenced, it should return a reference, not just assign one. The function should encapsulate its state, not assign a bunch of global variables.

My guess for using the time is so no two windows have the same reference (in theory, there is no guarantee, thanks [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)).

Comment: You are probably right about why the date is used, but worth pointing out that it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. Some clocks have a 15ms tick, so quite likely that a fast computer will create two dates with exactly the same time, even allowing for the creation of a window object and return. Much better to use a counter and check if a window with that name already exists to guarantee uniqueness

Comment: @RobG: Yeah I thought that too but thought I'd wouldn't bother adding it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference the `eval` is making there is setting an arbitrary variable... which you have no way of referencing again. I have no idea why anyone in their right mind would suggest this as a solution to opening a window, as your second piece of code demonstrates the "proper" way to do so.